# Editing Registry using C Giving warnings and not editing registry keys

Tags: c, registry

The following code *should* be changing these registry values, but it's giving warnings and even when the code actually runs, it won't set the values. It's not giving an error it's just not doing it. I've also confirmed the function and code are getting run. I fixed one warning by adding the `sizeof()` arguments, but the rest (see below the code) are still there and it still won't actually write to the registry. also when I try to edit a string value it works but not dword values.

```
//dependences for anyone who wants to try to fix it

#include <winreg.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>  

void startBCPE() {
    //Sets registery values for BCPE
    HKEY key;
    RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\Setup", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
    RegSetValueExA(key, "SystemSetupInProgress", 0, REG_DWORD, 1, sizeof(1)); //this line fails to edit the registry
    RegSetValueExA(key, "SetupType", 0, REG_DWORD, 2, sizeof(2)); //this line fails to edit the registry
    RegSetValueExA(key, "SetupPhase", 0, REG_DWORD, 3, sizeof(3)); //this line fails to edit the registry
    RegSetValueExA(key, "CmdLine", 0, REG_SZ, "cmd.exe", sizeof("cmd.exe")); //This line works however
    RegCloseKey(key);
    return;
}
```

And the warnings:

```
.\Fizz.c:17:64: warning: passing argument 5 of 'RegSetValueExA' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     RegSetValueExA(key, "SystemSetupInProgress", 0, REG_DWORD, 1, sizeof(1));
                                                                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:52:0,
                 from .\Fizz.c:5:
c:\mingw\include\winreg.h:108:23: note: expected 'const BYTE * {aka const unsigned char *}' but argument is of type 'int'
 WINADVAPI LONG WINAPI RegSetValueExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,const BYTE*,DWORD);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\Fizz.c:18:52: warning: passing argument 5 of 'RegSetValueExA' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     RegSetValueExA(key, "SetupType", 0, REG_DWORD, 2, sizeof(2));
                                                    ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:52:0,
                 from .\Fizz.c:5:
c:\mingw\include\winreg.h:108:23: note: expected 'const BYTE * {aka const unsigned char *}' but argument is of type 'int'
 WINADVAPI LONG WINAPI RegSetValueExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,const BYTE*,DWORD);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\Fizz.c:19:53: warning: passing argument 5 of 'RegSetValueExA' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     RegSetValueExA(key, "SetupPhase", 0, REG_DWORD, 3, sizeof(3));
                                                     ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:52:0,
                 from .\Fizz.c:5:
c:\mingw\include\winreg.h:108:23: note: expected 'const BYTE * {aka const unsigned char *}' but argument is of type 'int'
 WINADVAPI LONG WINAPI RegSetValueExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,const BYTE*,DWORD);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You might want to read through the documentation to see what's expected for each parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa

Comment: @RetiredNinja No unless i implemented the fix wrong
`
HKEY key;
DWORD SSIP = 1; //SystemSetupInProgress
DWORD ST = 2; //SetupType
DWORD SP = 3; //SetupPhase
RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\Setup", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
printf(RegSetValueExA(key, "SystemSetupInProgress", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&SSIP, sizeof(1)));
RegCloseKey(key);
`

Comment: `sizeof(DWORD)` and check the return values of all of the functions so you know where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RegSetValueExA api you cant just put 1 because its need var pointer with BYTE type just declare your var with dword type then convert it to BYTE here example:

```
HKEY key;
DWORD Num = 1;
RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\Setup", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
RegSetValueExA(key, "SystemSetupInProgress", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&Num, sizeof(1));
RegCloseKey(key);
```

Comment: Did i implement this wrong? when i ran this code it still didnt work or throw any warnings //Sets registery values for BCPE     HKEY key;     DWORD SSIP = 1; //SystemSetupInProgress     DWORD ST = 2; //SetupType     DWORD SP = 3; //SetupPhase     RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\Setup", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);     RegSetValueExA(key, "SystemSetupInProgress", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)SSIP, sizeof(1));     RegCloseKey(key);     return; and it still wont work

Comment: Sorry i forget cast SSIP as pointer RegSetValueExA(key, "SystemSetupInProgress", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&SSIP, sizeof(1));